# Signup user to ASP.NET Identity from Xamarin

Tags: asp.net, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have been stuck all day on a stupid problem with registering a user to my application.

Here is my code once the 'Register' button is clicked:

```
public ICommand RegisterCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async() =>
                {
                    var isSuccess = await _apiServices.RegisterAsync(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);

                    if (isSuccess){
                        Message = "Registered Successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Message = "Retry later";
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

Api services Register Async method:

```
 public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Email: "+email);
            var client = new HttpClient();

        var model = new RegisterBindingModel
        {
            Email = email,
            Password = password,
            ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

        HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
     //   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:63724/api/Account/Register", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: "+e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The Error that I get is:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in <6c708cf596db438ebfc6b7e012659eee>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

To me this is very frustrating as I can register a use using Postman with the exact same localhost address. I am following Houssem Dellai's Xamarin.Forms mvc web api tutorials which can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0v4srA4NhA&index=2&list=PLpbcUe4chE78YvgIMtmgNEmRGyGJcsQdF)

Comment: don't use localhost, use the IP or FQDN of your server.  Check your firewall.  If you are using IIS Express or the VS host server be sure it will accept external requests.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: @Jason in the video I have linked it doesnt mention about this?

Comment: "Connection refused" is a networking problem.  I gave you several suggestions to fix or debug this problem.  I have no idea if the video you linked to is accurate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an issue with httpclient during the development of my app. I believe there was an issue with the cross-platform implementation of the httpclient class. iOS didn't know how to handle it.

Instead I implemented a very simple httpclient library called flurl: http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/

First, you will need to install flurl in all project directories (iOS, Android, and the PCL) then the implementation is very simple.

```
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

public async Task<User> CreateUserAsync(RegisterUserModel userModel)
    {
        string url = "your/backend/here";
        //resp is a user object received and automatically converted into a c# object through the use of .ReceiveJson<typeofobject>();
        var resp = await (url).PostJsonAsync(userModel)
                                       .ReceiveJson<User>();
        if (resp.LoginSession != null)
        {
            //Raise my registered event to let other classes know to proceed
            OnUserRegistered(resp);
        }
        return resp;
    }
```

As you can see it makes httpclient implementation very simple. Hopefully this helps.